# Station coverage area

Tags: python, buffer, gis, geospatial, spatial

I have many points(stations with coordinates) and I want to find out their coverage area (further find out the average travel distance). People in these areas will go to the station in the area centre.

My basic thought is to draw some buffers which are tangent to each other (with no overlaps, each buffer only has one station). Then these buffers become the coverage area. I am not sure these areas are circle or random shapes.

I believe there could be some algorithms in Python or GIS softwares to address this. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you may be using QGIS have you tried http://gis.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Presumably each point has a radius with which to create station area. Can you confirm?

Comment: I just have the points. Yes, basically I only need to find out the radius for each station.